# jquery change next element after deleting prev

Tags: jquery, django

I have a code http://jsfiddle.net/hRRzK/3/. I want to reload whole `<ul>` after deleting one line to change numbers in `<var id="exset">4</var>` tag. I want to change numbers to every next lines from deleted line.

When I click to the link it send request to DB, remove line with id from DB and reassign new numbers to every next lines in DB. In same time JQuery remove line deleting apropriete `<li>` tag. After that I have in DB right numbers of lines, but in html - not. If I refresh page it show me right numbers because it is get from DB new data.

What is the best way to get right numbers in lines after delete one? Get new info back to JQuery after deleting line(is it possible)? Or subtract 1 from every next lines by J-script?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: I don't got what you want but i have fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/UpCSy/

Comment: It is exactly what I want. Could you explain what this part `$('#myLI li').each(function(){
                    $('.exset',this).html($(this).index() + 1);
               });` do? Just renumerate all lines from 1 to ...?

Comment: i am iterating every li present in element with id myLI and in each iteration i am getting element with class exset present in current li set it html to index of li adding 1 to it becoz index start from 0

Answer (score 0):

If those numbers are consecutive and they do not depend on values returned from the database, do it in Javascript. In my opinion, it would be undesirable to bother the database with a request in this case.